# smarty - function include_php set arrgument file from array

Tags: php, include, smarty

i need include php and file path in array.

controller

```
$object[0]['id'] = 1;
$object[0]['path'] = '/home/path/for/file/file.php';

$static_path[0] =  '/home/path/for/file/static_path.php'; 

$this->smarty->assign(array(
'object' =>     $object,
'static_path' =>    $static_path
));
```

in .tpl - this throw error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template...
and
Notice: Undefined index: path in /home/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_include_php.php(61) : eval()'d code on line 1

```
{foreach from=$object item=value}
 {include_php file=$value['path']} // trhow error msg
 {$value['path']} // this show string path correctly
{/foreach}
```

in .tpl - this is Ok

```
 {include_php file=$static_path[0]} //incude correctly
```

I want use foreach i need use var for array key.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'path' => '/home/path/for/file/file.php'
  )
);

// I'm not sure about this
$this->smarty->assign(array(
  'object' => $object
));

// May be the coorect way is, depending on template
$this->smarty->assign('object' => $object);
```

Comment: I update my answaer, smarty var assign is correct, i use it always.
I try change define of object